# How can I Create a Tableview Under Custom Tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am just thinking. Suppose, i have a tableview which have custom cell. It's simple. But My idea is that, when i click a tableview cell then another tableview is appear under that tableview cell, and again i click that cell then that sub tableview disappear. Similarly when i click second cell than work same. Is it possible? Please Provide me any idea or reference.

Comment: you cannot do that. Instead you need to add table cells below the table cell you clicked.

Comment: http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/expandable-and-collapsable-tableview.html Here you go try expandable tableview in objective-c in google and github

Comment: Why do you want another tableview?  How much additional data will you be displaying?  Its trivial to have the current cell resize and show more.  A stackview is a very good for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely possible, you're talking about **Expandable cells**.

[My example here](https://giphy.com/gifs/3og0IO6GNMSiyKM6Ck)

The general idea is that your custom cell has a tableview at the bottom of the cell, and what you do is just change the cell height to display said tableview, on tap.

It's not easy, I'm not gonna lie it took us a while to do it, but we managed, and I'm telling you, it's very possible.

You can find a lot of help using the **Expandable Cell** keywords.

Note that you're gonna find yourself handling a lot :

- What to do when the expanding cells is shown off screen?
- What to do when you're expanding the first/last cells ?
- What to do when expanding another cell ?
- What to do when scrolling inside that cell (a scrollview inside a scrollview !)

There are many cases where it'll work, but won't work fine, and there is gonna be a lot of fine tuning. Specially in our case where we have rounded corners, but only when the cell is expanded, and not in cases where it's the last or first cell (next to section header).

They look cool and make you feel proud, but don't say to your PM it'll be done in a week, because it's a pain to build.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show additional cell information, you can add more cells after the cell indexpath you have clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom table view cell class`CustomTableViewCell` by subclassing`UITableViewCell` class. And system will generate CustomTableViewCell.h, CustomTableViewCell.m, CustomTableViewCell.xib files for you.

Add protocols UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate in your CustomTableViewCell.h and implement the required methods in CustomTableViewCell.m files

Add a method for setting datasource and use the datasource for updating the table.

**NOTE:**

- Handle table-dequeue mechanism properly, otherwise you will end up
  with weird issues that may take time to investigate and resolve.
- If you use this custom cell for all the cells in your parent table then the gestures will only listened by the child table. So plan for that too.

Please visit my blog for the sample code. https://myioslearnings.blogspot.in/2017/03/nested-table-view-in-ios-objective-c.html